# Stuck on extremely low resolution 800x600; Native Resolution 1680x1050

Tags: 12.10, nvidia, dual-boot, resolution, monitor

I know this has been touched on by **a lot** of different threads by **a lot** of different people, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to fix it.

I'm on a **duel boot Windows 8/Ubuntu** system and have recently changed my monitor.  I am using **proprietary drivers** and my graphics card is a **Nvidia GeForce 660 Ti**, the new monitor I am using is a VX2025wm ([click here to view the manual](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3aBFrJ8BtTY_QJ%3awww.go-gddq.com/upload/2011-07/11071517485378.pdf%20&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESgU19ZzNGnXvSYITMZzS_zlqM-I5MdZMy3-WLJprNS_bBN2YAt-u3AJkjIianjTa28D0Hj2SSKdEcJdu_x8Gh1Jq6tIvtkEopXpYehF1NyGEUQIOn4RMco_FReyS03krPrA4BpD&sig=AHIEtbTD2QDToFpipirVRtSDPvZnDRPLsQ)).

I know that the monitor works on it's native resolution, because when booting on Windows 8 it automatically adjusts to 1680x1050.  I'm not sure if it's worth noting or not, but the old monitor would view GRUB on a higher resolution by default, while this one continues to use low resolution until booted into Windows 8.

I'm really at my wits end, I'm not really used to Ubuntu and I don't have a ton of experience with Linux in general.  Any help would be **greatly** appreciated.

I've included my **xorg.conf** file

**xorg.conf**

```
Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Razer Naga"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Razer Lycosa"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "VS10859 ViewSonic Widescreen"
    VendorName     "ViewSonic"
    ModelName      "DFP-0"
#   DisplaySize    433.44 270.9
    HorizSync      30.0 - 82.0
    VertRefresh    50.0 - 75.0
    ModeLine       "1680x1050_60.00" 146.25 1680 1784 1960 2240 1050 1053 1059 1089
    Option         "PreferredMode" "1680x1050_60.00"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "GTX 660 Ti"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 660 Ti"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Primary Screen"
    Device         "GTX 660 Ti"
    Monitor        "VS10859 ViewSonic Widescreen"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "1680x1050_60 +0+0; nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
        Modes      "1680x1050" "1280x1024"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Default Layout"
    Screen         "Primary Screen"
    InputDevice    "Razer Naga" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Razer Lycosa" "CoreKeyboard"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection
```

Comment: What version of the Nvidia driver are you using? Post the output of `dkms status`. Have you tried installing an experimental one in the "Additional Drivers" system application?

Comment: nvidia-current-updates, 304.51, 3.5.0-21-generic, x86_64: installed

I installed the experimental one last night, and it did nothing to change the problem, so I went back to current-updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working on it all day, I've come to the conclusion that problem lies solely in the monitor, **VX2025wm**'s have a history of problems for the **EDID** and **DVI Input**, such as **not showing native resolution**, **Signal Not Found** errors, and a bunch of other messy little things that aren't conducive to a fluid computing environment.

The solution lied in adding a **Custom EDID** to the **xorg.conf** file:

```
Option         "CustomEDID" "DFP-0:/etc/X11/viewsonic.raw"
```

For this specific monitor, I was able to find the EDID here:
http://blog.komeil.com/2008/06/fixing-edid-dvi-monitors-no-signal.html

I hope this helps anyone who is having problems with their native resolution and is certain that their Graphics Cards / Drivers are not the problem.

Example: **xorg.conf**

```
Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Razer Naga"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Razer Lycosa"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "VS10859 ViewSonic Widescreen"
    VendorName     "ViewSonic"
    ModelName      "DFP-0"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 82.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 75.0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "GTX 660 Ti"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 660 Ti"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Primary Screen"
    Device         "GTX 660 Ti"
    Monitor        "VS10859 ViewSonic Widescreen"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "CustomEDID" "DFP-0:/etc/X11/viewsonic.raw"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Default Layout"
    Screen         "Primary Screen"
    InputDevice    "Razer Naga" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Razer Lycosa" "CoreKeyboard"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection
```